# sort order as newest product first option in products in category in category edit does not showing in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, category, sku, sort

I want to sort category default sort as newly added SKU at top and oldest at last , this means new to old (SKU) default sorting in frontend of magento 2.

But i am not able to see option  => sorting as newest product first option in products in category in category edit
Please help me.

[image: "sorting as newest product first option in products in category in category edit]

Answer (score 0):

This is available for Magento Commerce only (not Magento Community Edition)

I've opened a Pull Request to update the documentation and clarify this, and it got "accepted" by Magento team.

New Updated Documentation indicates that the feature is only available to Magento Commerce. https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/category-products-sort.html